# Angular UI Grid - Custom Header Template and Filtering

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm looking for a good example of having a basic filter and having a custom template. I'm having trouble finding a good example on the tutorial sites. See attached plunk where I'm setting filtering and having a custom header template. Does the filtering need to be embedded into the header template?

http://plnkr.co/edit/VMETPu30iiFc3GYmZZRS?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.columns = [{ field: 'name', headerCellTemplate: '<div class="grand-total">Name</div>' }, { field: 'gender' }];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: $scope.columns,
    enableFiltering: true
  };

  $scope.remove = function() {
      $scope.columns.splice($scope.columns.length-1, 1);
  }

  $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.columns.push({ field: 'company', enableSorting: false });
  }

  $scope.splice = function() {
      $scope.columns.splice(1, 0, { field: 'company', enableSorting: false });
  }

  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.columns = [{ field: 'First', }, { field: 'Second' }, { field: 'third' }];
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.columns;
  }

  $scope.unsplice = function() {
      $scope.columns.splice(1, 1);
  }

  $http.get('https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      console.log(data)
    });
}]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom template and add it to your grid.Try this [post](http://brianhann.com/ui-grid-and-dropdowns/) you can get some ideas.I have updated some of the codes in blog post.you can do something like this.Hope this will help.[`Code Sample`](http://plnkr.co/edit/r0bNSroHIh2IoDJTNnKr?p=preview).