# Angular UI Grid column filter is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular js UI grid for table.

Although, everything showing perfect, textbox filter for specific column is not visible to me even after applied !!

My Code :

```
$scope.gridOptions = {

        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        showGridFooter: false,
        paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 30],
        paginationPageSize: 10,
        paginationOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        useExternalPagination: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        modifierKeysToMultiSelect: false,
        noUnselect: false,
        enableVerticalScrollbar: true,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: true,

    columnDefs: [
     {
                field: 'name',
                displayName: 'UserName',
                width: 150,
                cellTooltip: true,
                CellTemplate: '<div class="GridRow">{{row.name}}</div>',
                headerCellTemplate: '<div style="margin: 22px 0px 0px 0px;" ><span class="ui-grid-cell-contents GridHead">Last Run By</span></div>',
                cellClass:'tooltipclass',
                enableCellEdit: true,
                enableFiltering: true

            },
]}
```

Added enablefiltering but its still not showing textbox filter and neither it give any warning or error.

Anyone have any input on if I am missing something over here ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The textbox for filtering is not visible because you are providing a headerCellTemplate for that column. See here: [Angular UI Grid - Custom Header Template and Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278647/angular-ui-grid-custom-header-template-and-filtering). Another solution would be to copy the predefined template of headerCell from ui-grid into your code and modify it as per your requirements.